# how to define two dimensional vector which element is vector of variable size?

Tags: c++, vector, dimensional

I want to define a vector with 20 rows and 4 columns which its elements is vector with variable size like this

```
result={ 
   {1,2,3},{5,4},{1},{10,15,16}
   {5},{1,2},{1,2,3},{1,4,5,6}
    ...

}
```

Result at first is empty ...
some part of my code is written below and 'result' update if condition is true

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){

    hash_1=hash_images[i];

    for(int j=i+1;j<20;j++){

        hash_2=hash_images[j];
        dis=hammingDist(hash_1.c_str(),hash_2.c_str());

        for(int t=0;t<4;t++){

            if (dis<=t){
                  ? result[i][t].push_back(somthing);   
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you currently have?

Comment: std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {2, 3},
        {2, 7, 9}
    }; will work

Comment: I want to append item to vector but this dosnt work...result at end of code should be like that

Answer (score 0):

Define a 3-dimensional vector as follow:

```
vector<vector<vector<sth>>> S;
S.resize(20);
for (i=0 to 19)
   S[i].resize(4);
```

Then in your main loop you can resize your third dimension for each value after your calculation:

```
for(j=0 to 19)
   for(m=0 to 3){
      //your calculation
      k=S[j][m].size();
      S[j][m].resize(k+1);
      S[j][m][k]=value;
   }
```